# Getting buffer size error from struct.unpack when attempting to extract particular bytes of data from binary file

Tags: python

I am using `struct.unpack()` to gather specific pieces of data from a binary file.

```
point4, = struct.unpack("B", data[3:4])
point5, = struct.unpack("H", data[4:6])
```

point4 is expected to be a Uchar, and point5 is expected to be a Ushort. Format characters are used per https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html.

The above works just fine, and gathers the expected data correctly. However, if I try and combine both statements into something like: `point4, point5, = struct.unpack("BH", data[3:6])`,
I receive the following exception error: `unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`.
This is surprising to me, as I've been able to successfully extract the same data and more using a combined statement like:

```
point1, point2, point3, point4, point5, = struct.unpack("BBBBH", data[0:6])
```

I'm not certain why `point4, point5, = struct.unpack("BH", data[3:6])` would give me an error, but I would like to obtain this data in a single line rather than two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `data[3:6]` is only 3 bytes long, but by default the format `"BH"` is requires four bytes because a default alignment with padding is assumed. You can prove this with a:

```
print(f'{struct.Struct("BH").size=}')  # -> 4
```

See the [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) section of the `struct` module's documentation.

You can override that by explicitly specifying the byte order. i.e.

```
point4, point5 = struct.unpack("=BH", data[3:6])  # No error.
```

Also note that there's no reason to have that extraneous comma you have in your code on the left-hand side of the assignment expressions.